# How to create separate form widgets for ModelMultipleChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two Django Models: Team and Member. A single Member can be part of multiple teams. I am able to successfully bind a Form class to a CreateView, and, using the standard ModelMultipleChoiceField,can successfully save the Form using the save_m2m method.

However, the default widget for the field is not suitable for my user experience. Instead of using a picklist, I would like to create a separate select box for each number of selectable Members per team. For example, if the Team can have 7 Members, I would like to show 7 select boxes, rather than one pick list that a user selects 7 different objects from.

I understand I may not get a complete answer, but would appreciate any pointers on if I should be looking into overriding the Field with a custom MultiWidget, or if using an inline formset might be a more appropriate route. Or, something else...

Comment: Try using an inline formset, with the inline model being the through model of the m2m.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, I was thinking the inline formset route, but my question is: is an inline formset used primarily for creating an instance of one model, while also creating an instance of a second mode? In my case, I want to establish n instances of a ModelChoiceField basically.

Comment: A many to many field is nothing but an joining / bridging table (model) implicitly wrapped in a field, i.e. Django implicitly creates a _through_ model with foreign keys to the 2 related models. So an inline formset for this through table is what you want to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, I ultimately decided to stick with a single ModelForm for the Create Team form. Within this ModelForm, I dynamically create the number of fields I will need for the number of Member per team, and have created a function within the form that yields those fields.

I perform validation on those fields within the generic clean method of the ModelForm. I use the yield method within the Template to control displaying the individual fields.

I am sure it is not the most Django-y approach, as many people seem to use inlineformsets in theory, but this worked and the code does not seem overly hacky or unmaintainable.